# Retrieving JSON from remote domain, jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, getjson

I am trying to retrieve JSON formatted data from a remote domain (Zencoder video encoding API) in a jQuery script. When the script runs, it returns code 200 but Firebug shows an error (bold red highlight, circle with an X) on the address, and the response is empty.

Here is the jQuery script relating to this:

```
var checkStatus = function(jobID) {
        var url = 'https://app.zencoder.com/api/v2/jobs/' + jobID + '/progress.json?api_key=asdad3332d';
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            if (data.state == 'processing') {
                    //Do things to indicate job is still going
                    //Repeat this function to check status again
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        checkStatus(jobID);
                    }, 6000);
                } else if (data.state == 'finished') {
                    //Do some stuff
                } else if (data.state == 'failed') {
                    //Show errors, do other stuff
                }
            });
     };
```

And here is an example of JSON returned.

```
{"outputs":[{"id":18492554,"state":"finished"},{"id":18492553,"state":"finished"},{"id":18492555,"state":"finished"}],"input":{"id":12437680,"state":"finished"},"state":"finished"}
```

Finally, here are the response headers returned by Firebug:

```
Response Headers
Cache-Control   private, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Connection  close
Content-Length  174
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Date    Thu, 09 Feb 2012 16:06:13 GMT
Etag    "48f2d50a838e0e1e433f7c0ba197e787"
Server  ZenServer 0.1.0
X-Zencoder-Rate-Remaining   4999
```

Any help would be appreciated here. Scratching my head on this one

**DOCUMENTATION**
Here is the API documentation referring to obtaining the job progress, which is what I am trying to do..
https://app.zencoder.com/docs/api/jobs/progress

Comment: Well, you cannot make Ajax requests to external domains, it violates the same-origin policy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use jsonp for cross-domain requests, and the server will need to be able to accept jsonp requests and answer appropriately.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://app.zencoder.com/api/v2/jobs/1234/progress.js?api_key=asdf1234',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data){// your code here
    }
});
```

jQuery will append the `callback=blah` parm automatically.
See here the dataType section here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

The `data` parm in the success function will contain the object (not just a JSON string, but the object represented by the JSON string).

Comment: Their API documentation does mention JSONP, stating that you need to use the following URL format: `https://app.zencoder.com/api/v2/jobs/1234/progress.js?api_key=asdf1234&callback=asdf`, where the callback is optional. I tried this URL instead and had the same result - Code 200, error indication, no response. Do I need to change the code or just the URL (essentially, `.js` instead of `.json`)?

Comment: The `callback=asdf` means they accept jsonp requests. Just use the format in my answer and jQuery will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you append `callback=?` to the URL query? This should work, assuming the server supports JSONP.